# Find the point spectrum of $Ax=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda_n\langle x,e_n\rangle e_n$

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

If a set $\{e_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ is linearly independent, meaning that any finite number of the $e_n$ are linearly independent, can I conclude that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\alpha_ne_n=0\implies\alpha_n=0$$ for all $n$? I'm asking because I'm doing a question which asks for the point spectrum of the operator $A:H\to H$ where $H$ is a Hilbert space, $$Ax=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda_n\langle x,e_n\rangle e_n$$ where $\lambda_n$ is a non-increasing sequence of non-negative numbers, and $e_n$ is an orthonormal basis for $H$. So if $\mu$ is such that $Ax=\mu x$ for some non-zero $x$, then since $x$ can be written as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\langle x,e_n\rangle e_n$ we get
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda_n\langle x,e_n\rangle e_n=\mu \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\langle x,e_n\rangle e_n$$ which we can write as $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\lambda_n -\mu)\langle x,e_n\rangle e_n=0$$ so if what I first asked were to hold about linear indepedence I could conclude that for each $n$, either $\lambda_n -\mu=0$ or $\langle x,e_n\rangle=0$ which gives me the eigenvalues $\{\lambda_k:k\in\mathbb N\}$ with corresponding eigenvectors $e_k$. I don't think $\mu=0$ is necessarily an eigenvalue. I think this is the right answer I just don't know if it's justified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not true. Consider, for instance, the Hilbert space $\ell^2$ of all sequences $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n|^2<\infty$. Let $e_n$ be the sequence $0,0,\ldots,0,1,0,0\ldots$, with the $1$ located at the $n$<sup>th</sup> position. And let $e_0$ be the sequence $1,\frac12,\frac13,\frac14,\ldots$ Then $\{e_n\mid n\in\Bbb Z_+\}$ is linearly independent, but$$e_0=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1ne_n.$$

Comment: Can you explain how that provides a counter example to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\alpha_ne_n=0\implies\alpha_n=0$, since $e_0\neq 0$

Comment: Because $e_0-e_1-\frac12e_2-\frac13e_3-\cdots=0$, but no coefficient is $0$.

Comment: In that case, how could I find all of the eigenvalues without just making guesses?

Comment: Since $(e_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is an [orthonormal basis of $H$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Orthonormal_bases), your method works. I just provided an example that shows that simply assuming that the $e_n$'s are linearly independent is not enough.

Comment: Which property of $e_n$ being an orthonormal basis makes the above implication true? Could I say that the $\alpha_n$ would be given by $\langle 0,e_n\rangle=0$ for all $n$?

Comment: You can say that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\alpha_ne_n=0$, then, for each $k\in\Bbb N$, $\left\langle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\alpha_ne_n,e_k\right\rangle=0$. But $\left\langle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\alpha_ne_n,e_k\right\rangle=\alpha_k$.